# Primefaces datepicker does not pass time to backing bean

Tags: primefaces, datepicker

I have following datePicker with showTime="true", which allows user to enter date and time.

```
<p:datePicker id="deliveryTime" value="#{orderController.order.deliveryTime}" showTime="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
```

deliveryTime is java.util.Date (also tried with String, same result)

In Network tab of my browser i can see :

```
formContent:j_id_m_4:deliveryTime_input: 23/05/19 19:45
```

However, when I submit the form, date is correctly set, but bean receives time only as 00:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue: [DatePicker: Time is not set on Date Object #4625](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4625)

It also seemes the fix for this is delayed due to plans refactoring date related components to use Java 8 LocalDate/Time API: [Move to Java8 LocalDate/Time #4646](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4646)

Comment: @TomášJohanPrítrský: download the source, create a patch and use that version....

Answer (score 0):

You can force the component to execute an ajax request to update your bean property:

```
    <p:datePicker id="deliveryTime"
        value="#{orderController.order.deliveryTime}" showTime="true"
        pattern="dd.MM.yyyy">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
            listener="#{orderController.onDeliveryTime}"></p:ajax>
    </p:datePicker>

  public void onDeliveryTime(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent<Date> event) {
    Date date = event.getObject();
    this.order.setDeliveryTime(date);
  }
```

Tested with version 11.0.0

Comment: The issue was valid in 2019 for PrimeFaces 8. AJAX has nothing to do with the original issue. The issue has been resolved in PrimeFaces since then.